# npm run build missing script

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

We are facing these error on running the command **npm run build**

```
npm ERR! missing script: build
```

when adding a build in script section in package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "build": "webpack-cli app.tsx --config webpack-config.js"
    },
```

It tells webpack-config.js module not found my question is how to get webpack-cofig.js file in Laravel.

Comment: Is this a webpack-config.js file you have created in the root folder or are you wanting laravel's webpack-config file?

Comment: Yes, I ma wanting a webpack-config.js file.

Comment: If you have then please send me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a webpack-config.js in the same folder as your package.json file. You can find a webpack-config.js structure here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Answer (score 1):

Just run the command `npm run dev` in place of `npm run build`.

Answer (score 0):

As of Dec 2020

in the netlify build area, don't say `npm run build`,

change it to `CI= build configuration`.

In the continuous integration area of a Netlify app this is the latest build command. Remember Netlify keep changing this, so check with the admin and call them up.

Answer (score 0):

I was learning Laravel Jetstream and during it ,I had faced same problem after spending so much time in finding solution of this error. Finally ,I had found cause of error which was error of built-in code set-up of Jetstream.

```js
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

Above code should add 'app.css' and 'app.js' in the web page but it was getting executing in my case and giving me error while I try to compile "npm run build" in CMD which was showing the same in 'npm run build missing script'. So, I added them manually at their best possible position in the code.

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```