# I am trying to run npm build command on local but getting error using vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to run  npm run build command on local server  but unfortuntly getting error using vuejs. please help me how can i resolve that thanks.

**package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    
    },
```

**ERROR**

```
developer@developer-ThinkCentre-M93p:~/htdocs/yourstitichart/yourstitichart.com/cms$ npm run 
build
npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/developer/.npm/_logs/2021-03-14T19_37_00_327Z-debug.log
developer@developer-ThinkCentre-M93p:~/htdocs/yourstitichart/yourstitichart.com/cms$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "npm run build" fails with "npm ERR! missing script: build"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61516683/npm-run-build-missing-script)

Comment: Simply run `npm run production` for prod build or `npm run development` for development build

Answer (score 0):

you dont have a script as build

```json
 "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "build":"write something here"//<-------
    
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no build script. Looking at your package.json you probly want to run

```
npm run prod
```

To achieve the same behaviour

Comment: Actully i have some updated on vue js but latest work is runing local server but when i upload vue js project on live server it will not be updating latest . becasue i need to build project before live server.